# How do I stop SQL 2008 throwing errors when Full Text Search is not installed?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am calling **IF (0 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')) RETURN;** at the beginning of my full text search stored procedure. This should force the stored procedure to exit if full text search is not installed.

However I keep getting the typical **Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded** error message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It turns out that **FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')** returns a different value based on the context to which is it executed.

In my case it returned **0** within a query executed via SQL Management studio and **1** from within my stored procedure.

The correct code to use is **DATABASEPROPERTY(DB_NAME(), 'IsFulltextEnabled')** which returns a consistent result regardless of the context.